# Get single row using mysqli from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to display a single row data using mysqli.
The query is

```
$getfield = mysqli_query($con,"select name from as_users where user_id=34");
if (mysqli_num_rows($getfield) > 0) 
{
     while($rowpwd = mysqli_fetch_array($getfield))
        {
           echo $rowpwd['name'];
        }
}
```

if I print then i get

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($getfield));
echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [name] => abc
)
```

But getting the name inside the while loop doesn't work.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Print your data inside `while`

Comment: you can store them in separate variable inside while loop.

Comment: use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: Why you use WHILE loop for that but you want only a single row result.

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes Exactly. That's what I am looking for. It will always return a single row.

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes How to get a single row result using mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
$getfield = mysqli_query($con,"select name from as_users where user_id=34");
if (mysqli_num_rows($getfield) > 0) 
{
     $rowpwd = mysqli_fetch_array($getfield)['name'];
     echo $rowpwd;
}
```

OR

```
$getfield = mysqli_query($con,"select name from as_users where user_id=34");
if (mysqli_num_rows($getfield) > 0) 
{
   $rowpwd = mysqli_fetch_array($getfield);
   echo $rowpwd['name'];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot mate. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$getfield = mysqli_query($con,"select name from as_users where user_id=34");
if (mysqli_num_rows($getfield) > 0) 
$whatYouWant = array();
{
     while($rowpwd = mysqli_fetch_array($getfield))
        {
           //echo $rowpwd['name'];
           $whatYouWant[] = $rowpwd['name'];
        }
}



echo '<pre>';
print_r($whatYouWant);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Let me try with this.

Comment: I did var_dump($whatYouWant); but it says NULL. I am sure the value is there.

Comment: Thanks @VK321. Help me out

Comment: try echo mysqli_num_rows($getfield); and tell me what you get?

Comment: @VK321 It prints 1.

Comment: cool so you getting result. Now try  in next line print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($getfield));

Comment: @VK321 It prints nothing. But if I use mysqli_fetch_array then it prints the array.(the array which is in my above post).

Comment: have to leave. I will give it go and let you know why its not working in 2 hrs. ok

Comment: Its working for me. It should bring a result like this: Array
(
    [0] => Josiah
)

Comment: Yes solution by @user3196949 should work without doubt.

Comment: Worked with the solution from Adhan. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
mysqli_fetch_array
```

To: If you want key of row

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc
```

To:If you want index of row

```
mysqli_fetch_row
```

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: No error but it's not printing the value inside the loop.

Comment: inside loop what you get when you do print_r($rowpwd);